# How to use a defined brush resource in XAML, from C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources

So far I have this

```
<UserControl.Resource>
 <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="KeyDownBrush" .....>
```

Now I would like to access this defined resource when a key is pressed and replace the current objects fill with the KeyDownBrush, in C#.

I've tried this.Resource.Contains("KeyDownPress") and have been able to get True returned so I presume I am almost there but I'm not sure how to access the object and Parse it correctly to a Brush instance.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From within your UserControl:

```
var brush = this.Resources["KeyDownBrush"] as LinearGradientBrush;
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I thought I must be close, I just couldn't seem to find an example for this in the documentation where I was looking. 

For anyone else the C# I used looks like 
System.Windows.Media.LinearGraidentBrush aBrush = (System.Windows.Media.LinearGradientBrush)this.Resources["KeyDownBrush"];
aRectangle.Fill = aBrush;