# Apply custom brush in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, brush

I defined a custom brush like explained in [How to define and use resources in xaml so they can be used in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308868/how-to-define-and-use-resources-in-xaml-so-they-can-be-used-in-c-sharp) .

However when i try to assign this to a `Shape.Fill` or `Shape.Stroke` Property like this:

```
<Rectangle Stroke="MyBrush"/>
```

my application crashes with a `XamlParseException`. So how can i assign the custom brush by using only XAML code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well once inside XAML you cant specify the Resource name simply

```
<Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Source={StaticResource OfferByBrand}}"/>
```

If you are binding through code and its predefined there itself or

```
<Rectangle Stroke="{DynamicResource OfferByBrand}"/>
```

if specified inside the res.
Else as answered you would need to access through C# using

```
Application.Current.Resources["BlaBrush"] as LinearGradientBrush
```

Do check out [Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Create a `Brush` resource in a `ResourceDictionary`, and then you can reference that in your control definitions:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBrush">#727272</SolidColorBrush>
```

Or:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBrush" Color="Red"/>
```

Usage:

```
<Rectangle Stroke="{DynamicResource MyBrush}"/>
```