# Object created in XAML can't be called by x:Name in cs

Tags: c#, xaml

The following code represents a simple project in which I am trying to call objects created in XAML. So, I call them by `x:Name`. In the test UI I created a grid with three rows. The second and third row are being populated directly by Label2 and Label3, but the first row is populated indirectly, via `Window.Resources`.

The problem is that `myLabel2` and `myLabel3` are recognizable in MainWindow.xaml.cs (the AutoComplete works for them), but for `myLabel1` I receive en error message:

`The name 'myLabel1' does not exist in the current project`

**So, I guess that to problem derives from the fact that `myLabel1` was created inside `Window.Resources`.**

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

**This is the MainWindow.xaml code:**

```
 <Window x:Class="test2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="something">
            <Label x:Name="myLabel1" Content="Labe1"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource something}" />
            <Label x:Name="myLabel2" Content="Labe2" Grid.Row="1" />
            <Label x:Name="myLabel3" Content="Labe3" Grid.Row="2" />
        </Grid>

</Window>
```

**This is the MainWindow.xaml.cs code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace test2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            myLabel2.Content = "new content myLabel2";
            myLabel3.Content = "new content myLabel3";
            myLabel1.Content = "new content myLabel1";
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Could I possibly use in .cs something like `this.Resources["something"]` ?

That was loosely adaptive from [How to define and use resources in xaml so they can be used in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308868/how-to-define-and-use-resources-in-xaml-so-they-can-be-used-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Label 1 is in a different namespace Window.Window.Resources

Comment: @jdweng So, how can I bypass or resolve it?

Comment: namespace doesn't matter ... it's in DataTemplate ... so it doesn't exists until ContentPresenter  creates it (at run time - not compile time)...

Comment: @Selvin I am a rookie in C# so I have some difficulty to understand any commend. A small example or an exact solution path would be more than welcome.

Comment: it's XY problem ... simply you can't do this like this ... put your label instead ContentPresenter and `myLabel1` field will be genereted

Comment: @Selvin `ContentPresenter` is ideal for grouping parts of code, otherwise the code becomes unreadable. I feel that there should be another way to do so.

Comment: use binding instead code-behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one of the commenters mentioned, the contents of your DataTemplate don't exist until ContentPresenter instantiates it for a data object.

Since myLabel1 is inside a DataTemplate, you presumably would want your Label's content to be based on whatever data object you are displaying in your ContentPresenter.

You didn't say anything about your data object, so let's say that data is an instance of a class called Widget:

```
public class Widget
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Now the code that instantiates your data object (an instance of Widget) can set the value of the Title property. For example:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    myLabel2.Content = "new content myLabel2";
    myLabel3.Content = "new content myLabel3";

    Widget widgetItem = new Widget();
    widgetItem.Title = "new content myLabel1";

    // You could set this elsewhere, but I'm doing it here to simplify this example.
    myContentPresenter.Content = widgetItem;
}
```

Note that I gave your ContentPresenter a name so I could assign its Content for the sake of this example:

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="myContentPresenter" Grid.Row="0" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource something}" />
```

Then in your XAML, bind your Label's Content property to the data object's Title property:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="something">
        <Label x:Name="myLabel1" Content="{Binding Title}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

If you want to be able to change the value of widgetItem.Title after the initial binding and see that change reflect in the UI, then your data object's class (Widget in this case) will need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged or inherit DependencyObject. I will leave it up to you to investigate that independently.

Comment: The code works fine, yet I thought that changing the value of `widgetItem.Title` after the initial binding goes without saying (silly me). If that is not much trouble, I would be much obliged if you could help me there too. Please don't consider of me as a "hey dude, create the code instead of me" guy, I am just confused with C# and OO programming. In any case, your answer is accepted. Thank you for your time.