# c# how to use "implement INotifyPropertyChanged" or "inherit DependencyObject"

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am a beginner to C#, XAML and OO programming. Thus I want to create a UI example in order to understand how it works. It is very important the UI to be created in XAML, and many parts of the objects to be created inside `Windows.Resourses`.

I started my attempt with this question:
[Object created in XAML can't be called by x:Name in cs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58199103/object-created-in-xaml-cant-be-called-by-xname-in-cs) because I could not call objects created inside `Windows.Resourses`. The question was fully answered, but as it was mentioned, objects could be manipulated only during initialization.

Should I want to change some property otherwise, *implement INotifyPropertyChanged* or *inherit DependencyObject* should be used.

As illustrated below, Labels' contents are filled during initialization, but should I want to change content with Button Click, `my_WidgetItem` is not recognizable inside `onClick( )` function.

I am very confused with the use of both *implement INotifyPropertyChanged* and *inherit DependencyObject*. **Could somebody help my based on the code below?**

**This is the MainWindow.xaml.cs file:**

```
<Window x:Class="test2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="something">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label x:Name="myLabel1" Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding Title1}"/>
            <Label x:Name="myLabel11" Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding Title2}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="myContentPresenter" Grid.Row="0" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource something}" />
    <Label x:Name="myLabel2" Content="Labe2" Grid.Row="1" />
    <Label x:Name="myLabel3" Content="Labe3" Grid.Row="2" />
    <Button Margin="4" Content="click me" Grid.Row="3" Click="onClick"/>
</Grid>
```

**And this is the MainWindow.cs file:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace test2
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public class Widget
        {
            public string Title1 { get; set; }
            public string Title2 { get; set; }
        }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            myLabel2.Content = "new content myLabel2";
            myLabel3.Content = "new content myLabel3";

            Widget my_widgetItem = new Widget();
            my_widgetItem.Title1 = "new content while initialization a";
            my_widgetItem.Title2 = "new content while initialization b";

            myContentPresenter.Content = my_widgetItem;
        }

        private void onClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            /// Now, I want to change the Label's content.
            myLabel2.Content = "label changed"; /// O.K.
            my_widgetItem.Title2 = "new content after click";
            /// my_widgetItem does not exist in the current content.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`my_widgetItem` is a local variable, declared in MainWindow constructor. It can't be used outside of constructor.

you can retrive it back in `onClick` method:

```
private void onClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    /// Now, I want to change the Label's content.
    myLabel2.Content = "label changed"; /// O.K.

    var my_widgetItem = myContentPresenter.Content as Widget;
    my_widgetItem.Title2 = "new content after click";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you store a reference to the `Widget` that you create in the constructor, you can access it directly in your event handler:

```
private Widget my_widgetItem;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    myLabel2.Content = "new content myLabel2";
    myLabel3.Content = "new content myLabel3";

    my_widgetItem = new Widget();
    my_widgetItem.Title1 = "new content while initialization a";
    my_widgetItem.Title2 = "new content while initialization b";

    myContentPresenter.Content = my_widgetItem;
}

private void onClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myLabel2.Content = "label changed"; /// O.K.
    my_widgetItem.Title2 = "new content after click";
}
```

But for the `Label` in the `ContentTemplate` that is bound to `Title2` to get updated, the `Widget` class must also implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8) and raise change notification events:

```
public class Widget
{
    private string _title1;
    public string Title1
    {
        get { return _title1; }
        set { _title1 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private string _title2;
    public string Title2
    {
        get { return _title2; }
        set { _title2 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```